# How to use confirm_form

Tags: forms

OK this one is driving me nuts. I've read the other question posted on DrupalAnswers and several threads on the Internet, but I still can't work this out.

In my menu hook I have this:

```
$items['import'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('_my_module_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

Then I have these functions:

```
function _my_module_form($form_state) {
 if(!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])) {

  $form ['some_textarea'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textarea',
   '#rows' => 25,
   '#cols' => 10,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => 'Import',
  );

  return $form;
 } else {
  drupal_set_message('hello');
  return confirm_form($form);
 }
}

function _my_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
 if(!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])) {  
 }
}

function _my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 if(!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])) {
  $form_state['storage']['confirm'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 } else {
  drupal_set_message('hello2');
 }
}
```

When I submit the form, nothing happens. I would expect to see the drupal message 'hello', but instead I just get the original form again. However, if I submit the form a second time, then I see a drupal message saying 'hello2'.

Why does the comfirm_form bit not get executed? It seems to me like the form state is not being rebuilt so the 'else' part of the conditional never gets executed.

Note: I am pretty sure form_validate is not needed, but I just put an empty definition in there in case.

Comment: As side note, [confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/confirm_form/6) requires at least three parameters.

Comment: And you're missing something to transfer the values of the original form in your submit function. Something like `$form_state['storage']['original_form'] = $form_state['values'];` would suffice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like my issue was here:

```
function _my_module_form($form_state) {
```

Should have been:

```
function _my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
```

Comment: Drupal 6 uses `_my_module_form(&$form_state)`, while Drupal 7 uses `_my_module_form($form, &$form_state)`.